# EC2 - Make Windows instance accessible from anywhere (XAMPP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've launched an EC2 instance on AWS, no after setting up XAMPP and uploading all my archives it's now time to make the site public.

Thing is that I've already tried to put all the firewall on windows allowing inbound and outbound connections to "allow" and then also on my AWS Security groups this:

Inbound:

`HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0`

`HTTP TCP 80 ::/0`

`Custom TCP Rule TCP 0 - 8080 0.0.0.0/0`

`Custom TCP Rule TCP 0 - 8080 ::/0`

Outbound:

`All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0`

As i mentioned before, i allowed all inbound and outbound connections on the windows firewall of the instance.

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix this issue to make the server accessible from the IP that amazon assigned my instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check:

- (Obvious One) Make sure the application is listening on port 80 / 8080 (You mentioned both ports in SGs. Not sure on which port your application is running)
- If you are planning to access your application over the internet, make sure you have public IP assigned to your instance.
- Check your NACLs if both inbound and outbound rules are added. If you are accessing the app from a specific VPC / OnPrem network, add it to NACLs. If you dont want to restrict your app and want to access over internet, make sure you have 0.0.0.0/0 is added in NACL inbound and outbound
- If accessing the app over internet, you need to have Internet gateway assigned to your VPC.

Hope this helps troubleshooting your issue. Provide more details like, you instance is in public subnet or private subnet. Weather you are accessing app from within the VPC or over internet etc.